# adding a certain value to 3-d array in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have a 3-d array and i want to create a new array that each second elements of 3-d array must be increased by 1 until the second element reach to a certain value.

for example i have a 3-d array like below as an input and need to obtain my expected output :

```
#input = [[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4]],[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4]]]


#This is my expected output:

[[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4]],[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4]],
 [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5]],[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5]],
 [[1,3],[2,4],[3,5],[4,6]],[[1,3],[2,4],[3,5],[4,6]],
 [[1,4],[2,5],[3,6],[4,7]],[[1,4],[2,5],[3,6],[4,7]],
 [[1,5],[2,6],[3,7],[4,8]],[[1,5],[2,6],[3,7],[4,8]]]
```

Comment: Did you try anything? It's always a good idea to show some effort, no matter how good you think your own code is... Also, do you have to do this in "native Python" or is `numpy` an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `numpy` module, you could do

```py
import numpy as np

# initial nested list to numpy nd array
arr = np.array([[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4]],
                [[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4]]])

# expand n times along axis 0 ("x")
n = 3
arr = np.repeat(arr, n, axis=0)

# what you want to add
add = np.repeat(np.arange(n), arr.shape[1]*2)

# bring to adequate shape
add.shape = arr.shape[:2]

# perform addition
arr[:,:,1] += add
```

`arr` would now be

```py
array([[[1, 1],
        [2, 2],
        [3, 3],
        [4, 4]],

       [[1, 1],
        [2, 2],
        [3, 3],
        [4, 4]],

       [[1, 2],
        [2, 3],
        [3, 4],
        [4, 5]],

       [[1, 2],
        [2, 3],
        [3, 4],
        [4, 5]],

       [[1, 3],
        [2, 4],
        [3, 5],
        [4, 6]],

       [[1, 3],
        [2, 4],
        [3, 5],
        [4, 6]]])
```